# Is showing a progress dialog twice in an activity problematic?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

In my app there is an activity which does two AsyncTask in background one after another.

In these AsyncTasks onPreExecute I have the code below(progressDialog is private):

```
progressDialog=UI.getProgressDialog();
progressDialog.show();
```

The UI class is a class which implements some layout management, and in method getPregressDialog() I explicitly create **new** ProgressDialog and returns that new ProgressDialog to the caller.

In the onPostExecute() method of AsyncTasks I have the code below:

```
 if(progressDialog.isShowing())
     progressDialog.dismiss();
```

After first task executed and progressDialog dismissed, the second one appears. But never dismisses. It seems the condition isShowing() returns false(Obviously I can see the progress dialog);

Any suggestions?

Comment: define progressDialog globally and use progressDialog.show in first asynktask then use
    if(progressDialog.isShowing())
     progressDialog.dismiss();
in second asyntask...!

Comment: Yes, it's a private field in the class.

Comment: may be it cause delay because of heavy data from server or any other side in asyntask when you use it twice but you can use some different approach like. i said in above comment..... also make it public...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A variable that is public means that any class can access it. It is
>   useful for when the variable should be accessible by your entire
>   Activity or Application .

- You can use `if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {  }`
- Declare `public` instead of `private` Variable .**<s>private</s>**

> public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

Comment: Let me inform please .

Comment: @Sepinood Move ahead .Happy coding